# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges if and only if $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} a_k$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Question: Let m be a positive integer. By using the definition of convergence of a series,prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges if and only if $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} a_k$ converges.

I have no idea where to start. I know that since it is an if and only if proof, we have to prove it both ways, forwards and backwards, that if $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} a_k$ converges then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges, and if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges then $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} a_k$ converges. I also feel like the proof requires partial sums, I just don't know exactly how.

Comment: use the definition of convergence

Comment: Think of this this way: in the second sum, we just ignore the first $m-1$ terms in the sum - we therefore ignore a constant value. For example, consider the case $m=3$. The first sum is then $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7+...$ and the second is $a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7+...$. Note that other then extra $a_1+a_2$, a constant value, there is no difference between the two sums.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You know that for $n>m$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}a_k+\sum_{k=m}^{n}a_k
$$

And $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}$ doesn't depend on $n$. Can you take it from this ?

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=s$, I shall prove that $\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k=s-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}a_k$. In order to do that, I take $\varepsilon>0$. I know that there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies\left|s-\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right|<\varepsilon.$$But then if $n\geqslant\max\{N,m\}$, then$$\left|\left(s-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}a_k\right)-\sum_{k=m}^na_k\right|<\varepsilon.\tag1$$Can you do it in the other direction?

Answer (score 0):

Let $m\geq1$ and let for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ and for every $n\geq m$, $t_{n-m+1}=\sum_{k=m}^{n}a_k$. Then for every $n\geq m$ we have $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}a_k+t_{n-m+1}$ and because $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}a_k$ is just a constant, the limit of $s_n$ exists if and only if the limit of $t_{n-m+1}$ exists, as $n\to\infty$.